# Using webkit database storage for highscores

Tags: javascript, database, html, webkit

I just made a simple HTML5 game for mobile webkit. I have made a simple function that inserts the record into the database:

Javascript:

```
db = openDatabase('highscores', '1.0', 'Whackem Highscores', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE scores (id unique, int,text)');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (?,?,?)',["",score,date1]);
});
```

It doesn't seem to do anything!?

How can I fix this?

I also have to make a loop that prints out the highest scores, If you have any advice on something like that, it would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something more like:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE scores (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, score INTEGER, date_added TEXT)');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO scores (score, date_added) VALUES (?,?)', [score, date1]);
});
```

Note that you'll have to explicitly DROP your original table.

Each `executeSql` command takes a success and a failure handler as arguments after the parameter list; adding those will help debug failed queries in the future, as they otherwise fail silently.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`localStorage`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) instead. It will be much simpler to use (assuming you aren't going to store hundreds of thousands highscores on each client).

Also, WebSQL has been deprecated in favor of [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) (although the latter is not in shipping browsers yet).

`localStorage` is simply a persistent object that holds strings, so you can feed it JSON with all your (small) data.

```
localStorage['highscores'] = JSON.stringify(your_highscores_table);
```

Reading:

```
your_highscores_table = JSON.parse(localStorage['highscores']);
```

Or you could split it using different keys rather than lumping everything in `'highscore'`.

Comment: Could you provide me with some sample code, or point me in the right direction so I can learn how to use LocalStorage?

Comment: @Ben: It's simple: `localStorage['somekey'] = 'somevalue';`. then get it by using `somevalue = localStorage['somekey'];`. Just note that only String can be saved.